# Sql loader: Loading .CSV files with embedded \r\n into oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I have a .csv file where data in some columns have one or multi \r\n. I need to load them into oracle without these \r\n but SQLLDR gives an error.

below are the sample of records:

R1:

```
"A", "B", "
CDE
FGH" , ...
```

R2:

```
"A", "B", "
CDE

FGH" , ...
```

R3:

```
"A", "B", "C
DEF
GH" , ...
```

R4:

```
"A", "B", "C
DE" , ...
```

I used

- continueif last != '"' ,
- "STR '\r\n'" and
- replace (:ColumnName, chr(13) || chr(10), ' '),

  in the control file, but these solutions didn't work. So, How can I handle this?

**Edit:** Here is header of my control file:

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT=TRUE)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'E:test.csv'
INTO TABLE TEMP
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
...
```

Comment: Check out this: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8764530300346290066

Comment: Thanks but I think the questions are different.

Comment: use `dos2unix`  to remove carriage returns before the start of processing.

Comment: @KaushikNayak  Records are also splitted with \r\n. What happend If I remove that? (Both \r\n between fields and at the end of the record are deleted)

Comment: @DAVID_ROA, the link I posted describes also how to define line break characters, and hence it **IS** relevant to your question (or so I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
I should use : CONTINUEIF NEXT PRESERVE(1) != ' " ', because records starts with ' " ' and As long as the next lines are opposed to ' " ', they all count as one record.